# How to know how rails loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How rails know - is it loaded from console, or by rake, or by something other?

I tried to parse `ARGV` but with no success. Rails rewrite it after initialization.

Comment: why does it matter how it got loaded? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to require a group in bundler depending what is loaded. I.E. I want to load "pry" just when `rails console` ran

Comment: For that you can add/customize your `.irbrc` file, which will run every time you start IRB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `if defined? (Rails::Console)`

Comment: @web-tiki he provide the good solution, but I really wonder how to define, because sometimes I have another needs